# I'm trying to create https selfsigned keystore for android local server

Tags: android, ssl, https, keytool

I'm trying to make its certification of ssl for https with commands here. Do I miss something for creating certification?

keytool -genkey -alias selfsigned -keystore selfsigned.keystore -storepass password -validity 360 -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1 -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar

Comment: and I tried with commands and got "keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format: null" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Answer, I solve it myself, It gives me errors but keystore created to destination. and used it well

I've used this command to make selfsigned key.

keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore selfsigned.keystore -storepass blabla -validity 9999 -keysize 2048 -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1 -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.ja